# Dynamic nested multidimensional arrays in php for treegrid table? Level of array should be dynamic

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays, treeview

I want to make a tree grid table and need to make dynamic array which contain its parent and child. Level of array should be dynamic according to its child and parent level ?

Array now looks like below in which all the child and parent are together :

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [id] => 100 [name] => name1 [description] => name_desc1 [parent_ref_id] => 0 [parent_ref_name] => NULL) 
    [1] => Array ( [id] => 101 [name] => name2 [description] => name_desc2 [parent_ref_id] => 100 [parent_ref_name] => parent1 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [id] => 102 [name] => name3 [description] => name_desc3 [parent_ref_id] => 101 [parent_ref_name] =>parent2) 
    [3] => Array ( [id] => 103 [name] => name4 [description] => name_desc4 [parent_ref_id] => 100 [parent_ref_name] => refname3)
    [4] => Array ( [id] => 104 [name] => name5 [description] => name_desc5 [parent_ref_id] => 100 [parent_ref_name] => refname4)
    [5] => Array ( [id] => 105 [name] => name6 [description] => name_desc6 [parent_ref_id] => 101 [parent_ref_name] => refname5)
    e.t.c
)
```

Comment: Okay, and what have you tried yourself in order to achieve this?

Comment: Post your expected output along with your attempts